# How to parse a XML file using Linq - descendants

Tags: c#, xml, linq, parsing

I am having trouble using `XDocument` Linq-to-XML in C# to parse the following XML:

```
<matches count="9">
<books count="4">
    <book>
        <key>books/batman_dark_knight_returns/frank_miller</key>
        <title>Batman: The Dark Knight Returns</title>
    </book>
    ...
</books>
<movies count="4">
    <movie>
        <key>movies/batman_tales_of_dark_knight/boy_kirklan</key>
        <title>Batman: Tales of the Dark Knight</title>
    </movie>
    ...
</movies>
<music count="1">
    <album>
        <key>music/dark_knight/hans_zimmer</key>
        <title>The Dark Knight</title>
    </album>
</music> </matches>
```

A snippet of my very very wrong code is

```
var data = from query in xmlFeed.Descendants("books")
           select new Book
           {
               Title = (string)query.Element("book").Element("title"),

               count = (string)query.Element("stickers").Element("sticker").Element("count")

           };

searchListBox.ItemsSource = data;
```

Any help on how I can parse a xml like this that returns books, movies, tv shows in a long list that I can bind to a list box?

Thanks

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve. What *exactly* do you want the results to be? Does a single `books` element have multiple `book` elements? What does the `count` property of a `Book` mean? Where do stickers come in?

Comment: @Jon Hi Jon thanks for the reply. The api I am using returns matches according to a search query. The count is the number of found objects that could be of type book, movie, recording artist etc. So a query could return 9 items which are made up of 4 books, 4 movies and 1 artist. I'd like to list the search results in one listbox. User can then select the item to view more info.

Comment: But in your sample code you're assigning `count` as a property of a single book, which really doesn't look right. Please could you look at my answer and comment on whether that solves your problem, and if not what you want changed?

Answer (score 4):

I *suspect* you want something like:

```
var books = xmlFeed.Descendants("book").Select(x => Book.FromXElement(x));
var movies = xmlFeed.Descendants("movie").Select(x => Movie.FromXElement(x));
var albums = xmlFeed.Descendants("album").Select(x => Album.FromXElement(x));

// I'm assuming you're using .NET 4 here, otherwise it becomes slightly uglier.
var allResults = books.Concat<object>(movies).Concat(albums).ToList();
```

That's assuming you add a static `FromXElement` method to each of your classes, which I've generally found to be a clean way of handling this sort of thing. You can do it inline if you want, but it makes the query code get bigger and bigger as you start fetching more bits.

Answer (score 0):

If all `key`'s are followed by the `title` node:

```
var all = xmlFeed.Descendants("key").Select(x => new {
          Key = x.Value,
          Title = ((XElement)x.NextNode).Value
          // else the Title would be
          // Title = x.Parent.Element("title").Value
          }).ToList();
```

This gets all the Key's and Titles as a long list.